# Create NativeScript Modal View without outlined whitespace?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have an Angular NativeScript project and I am trying to create a modal view that does not cover the full screen and has a semi-transparent background. What I am trying to achieve works properly on iPad, but on iPhones a white outline appears and the page zooms out when a modal view is clicked. I would like to replicate the functionality of the iPad on the iPhone.

Attached is a photo of the iPad and iPhone[image: I would like to replicate the functionality of the iPad on the iPhone.]

Comment: Which one from your screenshot is modal view? The whole toolbox is modal view Or just the content in center? Can you share a Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=iC2pnQ&v=143 This simple playground does it. Where the old page shrinks and a white outline appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the default presentation style to `OverFullScreen` which prevents the shrink animation.

```
const options: ModalDialogOptions = {
  viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef,
  fullscreen: false,
  ios: {
    presentationStyle: UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen
  },
  context: {}
};
this.modalService.showModal(ModalComponent, options);
```

If you haven't installed `tns-platform-declarations`, you may have to declare `UIModalPresentationStyle` to avoid TS errors

```
declare var UIModalPresentationStyle;
```

Comment: that worked beautifully. Thank you. I have learned a lot from you Manoj :)